# Is it actually impossible to make a local backup from a remote SQL Server DB with SSMS Express?

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have a site in development, running on an inexpensive host. I can use SSMS Express to manage the database remotely... but I actually *cannot* make a local backup of this database on my own computer? Is this true??

I can't make a backup on their server because I have no idea where my FTP access points to.

What's the easiest, no-fuss way to get a .bak file of the remote DB on my computer? I've been searching for hours and no answers.

1GB download to install SSMS and it can't make a local backup. Unbelievable.

Comment: how big is the database? Are there too many tables? and a lot of rows?

Comment: "I can't make a backup on their server because I have no idea where my FTP access points to." - seems like an administration problem to me. Please try to remove bias from the title and explain how SSMS Express makes it 'impossible' to do the task. (If there is an SSMS Express limitation, make sure to discuss it directly and include relevant information in the title.)

Comment: There's just no way to create a backup file on my computer. It has to be written to the remote SQL Server filesystem, then copied to my PC (eg. via FTP, which is the only access I have.) I don't know what the physical paths are on the remote machine.

Comment: Backup is performed by the SQL Server engine not SSMS so the backup path needs to be somewhere the SQL Server engine can write to. Best you can do in SSMS is script out the database objects (possibly including data) and/or use the import/export wizard.

Comment: Thanks Martin. It's crazy, SSMS Express doesn't allow you to import anything later than SQL Server 2005 databases.

Comment: Aaaand scripting doesn't work, because it generates a SQL script that tries to create files using the physical path of the remote DB machine. THIS IS ABSURD.

Comment: yes you can take a backup on your local pc as long as sql server can see this drive(has access to your local drive) , share your drive and give full control to sql server process account given that sql server can see this drive take a backup on your local pc but you will have to use the UNC path for the backup location e.g `\\myPc\Sharedfolder\DB_Fullback.bak` etc

Comment: Thanks M.Ali, I don't think the SQL Server will allow me to share a local drive to it. After some trial & error configuration with the "Generate Scripts" option, I have managed to export & import via SQL commands.

Answer (score 0):

All right, if you're stuck like I am with regards to being unable to write or copy from a backup file on the actual filesystem of a remote SQL Server box (which I'd think shouldn't be all that unusual), AND if your DB is fairly small/simple, on a dev site, and you just need to grab a copy of the data, then maybe this will work for you.

(At least this may work as of the current release of SSMS Express in summer 2015. Future releases will undoubtably change dialog box layouts or wizard steps, so this will probably go out of date before too long.)

#### To export your DB as plain text SQL commands in SSMS Express:

Right Click Database Icon

Tasks -> Generate Scripts...

Intro -> Skip forever

Choose Objects -> Consider what you want here. You might want it to re-create the database and users, or you might only want selected table data (i.e., not the SQL Server user tables.) This is useful when your remote DB uses SQL Authentication and your local dev DB uses Windows authentication. Or when you've already created a DB with permissions set up the way you want and just need to import some tables into it.

Set Scripting Options -> Fairly obvious options EXCEPT...

-> **Advanced** -> Types of Data to Script -> Schema and data

The default is "Schema only" and you won't get your DB data.

"Schema Qualify Object Names" is true by default, you might want it off.

(By the way all of these settings will be forgotten the next time you generate scripts. So have fun memorizing everything you click.)

Summary -> Next

Then you'll get a local copy of your DB in executable SQL text format.

#### To import SQL to your local DB via SSMS

Connect to your local SQL Server. Create/Select the DB you want to import to (unless you exported a script that includes the DB creation commands.)

File -> Open -> File...

Open the SQL file you saved. You should be able to Execute it. You might need to go back and tweak the process it until it's outputing the SQL the way you need it.